# building mono's System.Configuration project failed with error "ProjectReference corlib-net not found"

Tags: mono

I want to make some bugfix in mono.
I have mono installed on my openSuse and download mono source code from github.
Then i want build System.Configuration project with this command:

```
xbuild System.Configuration-net_4_5.sln
```

and recieve 31 Errors, most of them like this

```
error CS0518: The predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
```

Also i recieve following warning:

```
warning : ProjectReference '..\corlib\corlib-net_4_5.csproj' not found, neither by guid 'some guid' nor by project file name 'path to project'
```

This project does exist in this location.
What's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the code change and then recompile the whole Mono following the instructions on how to compile Mono from source code. You cannot build individual projects, as the referenced projects cannot be resolved by 'xbuild' correctly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. can you explain me one more thing. I want work in MonoDevelop when i develop mono. But how i can do this, if i can't build it in monodevelop also? What is standart use case for develop mono in IDE?

Comment: If you want to debug into the stable Mono source code, you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277286/how-to-step-into-framework-source-code-in-monodevelop and I found @BenLast 's tip is enough. But if you compile Mono from source code, I have no idea what is the setup for debugging into source code.